# What is the best way to link a single CheckBox with a SQL column

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox

(I haven't written the code yet, just brainstorming)
Hi guys, just wondering of the best method to use for this problem;

```
If sql column == 1
set checkbox.checked

else
leave checkbox unchecked
```

or would it be better to declare a **Boolean** variable and use an if statement to set to **true** or **false** depending on the 1 or 0 returned from the dataset.

Comment: If you use bit datatype on SQL server, on your dataset it is mapped to a boolean already. Or within a model you can use a bool for that column.

Comment: If you are not using SQL Server, define an integer column with a 0/1 constraint on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the `Checked` property of your `CheckBox` with your column value. Try this:

```
YourCheckbox.Checked = sql_column == 1;
```

Comment: Although you are not _directly_ setting the value, you are performing a comparison and setting the checkbox to the Boolean result. You could equally use `sql_column == 'tree'`

Comment: @Tony Why could I equally use `sql_column == 'tree'`? What's the sense of this?

Comment: I was just trying to show that the code you posted is not _directly_ setting the value. What I should have explained is that the value used does not have to be a `1` or `0`, any comparison that results in a boolean would do. To directly set the checkbox you would use `YourCheckbox.Checked = sql_column` but that assumes the values of `0` and `1` are for `false` and `true` respectively, in some cases they are not. For instance, Visual Basic uses `-1` for `false`; so directly setting values from a database should be avoided, as you don't know what programming language may be used in the future